# C#: create a method using a stack

Tags: c#, methods, stack

I'm working on a C# project. I am trying to create a method in which I have to use a **stack**.

The project is about moving a group of planes in a specified time. The information of every aircraft is contained in a class called `FlightPlan` which contains: speed, initial position(x,y), final position(x,y), airline...

I have created this method:

```
public void Move(double time)
    {
        double distance = (time * this.Speed) / 60;
        double hyp = Math.Sqrt( (this.Destination.GetX() - this.Actual.GetX())^2 + (this.Destination.GetY() - this.Actual.GetY())^2 );
        if (hyp < distance)
        {
            this.Actual = this.Destination;
        }
        else
        {
            double cosine = (this.Destination.GetX() - this.Actual.GetX()) / hyp;
            double sine = (this.Destination.GetY() - this.Actual.GetY()) / hyp;
            this.Actual.SetX(this.Actual.GetX() + (distance * cosine));
            this.Actual.SetY(this.Actual.GetY() + (distance * sine));
        }
    }
```

This method will move the aircraft to the position that it will reach after the specified time.

Now, my question is: I have to create a method that allows me to go back to the last position (i.e undo the `Move` method). To do that, I must use a stack. I'm not really used to working with stacks and I don't get to do this method after thinking too much.

The stack should store all the positions when the aircraft is moved after every cycle of time, and then I have to pop them from the stack so the last position it reached will be the first position that leaves the stack.

Could you guys help me with code? Even though it's not exact because you don't know all the variables created, I just need some hint on how to do it.

I think it should start like (because you don't need the time now) `public void MoveBack ()`

Thank you on beforehand.

Comment: Are you asking how to use stack or how you should design your program to be able to undo (using a stack) ?

Comment: if you rename the variables, replace D with Distance...is it stands for Distance? that will increase the readability of the code.

Comment: I'm asking how I should design the program to undo the position it reached after using Move.

More or less I know how to do it. I have to store in the stack all of the positions when I use Move. And then I have to pop those positions to move it back. 

However, I can't make it work, so it'd be helpful some code help. Maybe I have to modify something from Move method. @Zee

Comment: @kennyzx I just did it, if that makes you guys understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggestion the following. Instead of SetX and SetY functions, you create a method SetPosition.  That function then uses a stack to keep a history of the changes. Something like this

```
void SetPosition(double x, double y)
{
    positionHistoryX.Push(x);
    positionHistoryY.Push(y);
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}
```

Then you can implement a method called MoveToLastPosition() that pops the x- and y-positions from the stack and put them in the X and Y properties.

**EDIT**: Following Zee's comment, just wanted to point out that it is better to have one stack which stores all information about a location, but I didn't do that because I didn't any structure for that to use. So maybe what you can do is the following

```
struct LocationInfo
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Time;
}
```

Then you can add a field of type Stack to your class and start using it in your Move method.

Comment: this is a stack you dont want to push x and y separately, besides time is missing. Every push to the stack should contain all the information required for the undo

Comment: Yes, this is why I suggested implementing a SetPosition() method, so that there is always pushes to the X stack and Y stack at the same time. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @Rafid okay, that sounds like a good idea. But the stack definition and code, where should I write it? I mean inside Move method or MovetoLastPosition() method or in the main program?

Comment: @user3780731, I would put it the class that contains the Move method. Maybe you can share a larger portion of the code for us to be able to give better suggestions.

Comment: @Rafid I think I'm going to try to edit the changes you suggested. If I can't make it work I will tell you. Thank you by the way.

Comment: Sure, yeah, I am just suggesting an idea, but you have to make changes to it to fit it with you code.

Comment: Thanks so much @Rafid it is working now, I implemented that SetPosition method and the struct, so it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

This should push you in the right direction.

```
public class MainClass
{
    private Stack<Coordinates> _coordinateHistory;  //Stores the coordinate history

    //Base class that initializes the stack of coordinate history.
    public MainClass()
    {
        _coordinateHistory = new Stack<Coordinates>();
    }

    //Used to create a new coordinate object and add it to the coordinate history stack.
    public void AddCoordinates(double x, double y)
    {
        _coordinateHistory.Push
        (
            new Coordinates(x, y);
        )
    }

    //Gets the next coordinate in the history stack.
    public Coordinates GetNextCoordinates()
    {
        return _coordinateHistory.Pop();
    }

    //Optional method to do all the calculations needed to get distance.
    public double CalculateDistance(Coordinates c1, Coordinates c2)
    {
        //Do your distance calculations here and return the result;
        return null;
    }
}

//Coordinates object that contains the X, Y, time stamp and optionally, latitude and longitude.
public class Coordinates
{
    private double _x;
    public double X
    {
        get { return _x;  }
        set { _x = value; }
    }

    private double _y;
    public double Y
    {
        get { return _y;  }
        set { _y = value; }
    }

    //Optional
    private double _latitude;
    public double Latitude
    {
        get { return _latitude;  }
        set { _latitude = value; }
    }

    //Optional
    private double _longitude;
    public double Longitude
    {
        get { return _longitude;  }
        set { _longitude = value; }
    }

    /*Recommend using a datetime object over a double in order to keep track of timestamps as
      it offers precision as well as funcionality. Eg. Time span in ticks between time date time objects */
    private DateTime _time;
    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return _time;  }
        set { _time = value; }
    }

    //Base constructor
    public Coordinates() { }

    //Overloaded constructor that accepts the X and Y coordinates as parameters.
    public Coordinates(double x, double y)
    {
        InitializeCoordinates(x, y, DateTime.Now);
    }

    //Overloaded constructor that accepts the X and Y coordinates, and a date time object.
    public Coordinates(double x, double y, DateTime time)
    {
        InitializeCoordinates(x, y, time);
    }

    //Private method that initializes the variables of this coordinate object.  This is to reduce unnecessary replicated code.
    private void InitializeCoordinates(double x, double y, DateTime time)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _time = time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added additional values just in case you can find a use for them such as latitude and longitude.